# Rich text plugin for Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I know that there are already richtext plugins for grails like RichUI, CKEditor, FckEditor etc, but is there any plugin which binds itself with grails so well that when I can use a rich textbox just by specifying widget attribute under the constraints clause
Example

```
static constraints = {
        dateCreated display:false
        lastUpdated display:false
        question nullable:true, widget:"richtext"
    }
```

Comment: FYI, I think the widget key is only used when generating scaffolded views

Comment: @Don I am pretty sure that widget plays role when we do generate-all. I commonly use widget:"textArea" and I do not remember an instance where my textArea got converted to textbox because I got rid of scaffolding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of such a feature, but I guess you can solve this by yourself:

- use `install-templates` to get the scaffolding (and `generate-all`) templates http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html
- you'll find a file called `renderEditor.template` and in this a method called `renderStringEditor`
- there you'll find how to render the input tag based on the value of the `widget` constraint

Would be a nice addition to the existing plugins.

btw: FckEditor seems to be a little bit old and I guess CKEditor should be used instead.